# Fast fit of linear function. Matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, curve-fitting

In my code I have a bottleneck, where I am fitting a linear function to my data. Simply fit a line to data points and find parameters `k`, `b` and `R^2` for equation `y=k*x+b`.

There are plenty of functions in MATLAB to do it. I use the `polyfit()` function. But it seems like overkill for my needs. The problem is I have to perform a really a big amount of these fits (10^8 or near it).

Here is an example my code:

```
nLines=5; % may be up to 10^8;
X=cellfun(@(x) rand(randi([50 100]),1),num2cell([1:nLines]'),...
    'UniformOutput',false);
Y=cellfun(@(x) rand(numel(x),1),X,...
    'UniformOutput',false);
K=nan(numel(X),1);
B=nan(numel(X),1);
R=nan(numel(X),1);
for iLine=1:numel(X)   
   coefs = polyfit(X{iLine}, Y{iLine}, 1);
   yf=polyval(coefs,X{iLine});
   K(iLine)=coefs(1);
   B(iLine)=coefs(2);
   R(iLine)=corr(Y{iLine},yf);
end
```

**Could you help with some faster solution for such massive linear fits?**

---

P.S. I am using MATLAB R2017b, with the following toolboxes:

```
Optimization Toolbox 
Signal Processing Toolbox 
Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox
```

Comment: `polyfit` is pretty quick, in tests compared to `mldivide` (as demonstrated [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/linear-regression.html#bq42ad8)), it is actually quicker for large datasets. This would involve replacing the `polyfit` line with this: `coefs = [X{iLine}, ones(size(X{iLine}))] \ Y{iLine};`. A better approach might be trying to vectorise your code, processing more than one line at a time.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: 10^8 fits but how many points per fit in the real data?

Comment: From 10 to 1000.  200 points per line on average.

Comment: your bottleneck is that you need to do this row by row because the row size is changing. Otherwise you can apply matrix inversion or svd to solve it all at one go

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately in this case they ARE of different sizes. Nevertheless, I have similar problem for same size situation. Could you clarify what you wrote. It will be super for my other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found an answer. I may make my seqs of the same size just adding NaNs to the end this variant is incredibly faster, then `polyfit` solution.

```
%% Generate data
nLines=10^3; % may be up to 10^8;
X=cellfun(@(x) rand(randi([50 100]),1),num2cell([1:nLines]'),...
    'UniformOutput',false);
Y=cellfun(@(x) rand(numel(x),1),X,...
    'UniformOutput',false);
K=nan(numel(X),1);
B=nan(numel(X),1);
R=nan(numel(X),1);
dur1=[];
dur2=[];
%% Small hack 
% elongate all seqs by NaNs to obtain same size
longestLineSize=max(cellfun(@(x) numel(x),X));
matrixX=[];
matrixY=[];
N=[];
for iLine=1:numel(X)
    matrixX=[matrixX,[X{iLine};nan(longestLineSize-numel(1,X{iLine}),1)]];
    matrixY=[matrixY,[Y{iLine};nan(longestLineSize-numel(1,X{iLine}),1)]];
    N=[N, numel(1,X{iLine})];
end
for iRep=1:100
%% Vectorized approach
start=tic;
sumX=nansum(matrixX);
sumY=nansum(matrixY);
sumX2=nansum(matrixX.^2);
sum2X=sumX.^2;

sum2Y=sumY.^2;
XY=matrixX.*matrixY;
sumXY=nansum(XY);
nominator=N.*sumXY-sumX.*sumY;
denominator=(N.*sumX2-sum2X);

k=nominator./denominator;
b=(sumY-k.*sumX)./N;
r=nominator./sqrt(denominator.*(N.*nansum(matrixY.^2)-sum2Y));
dur1(end+1)=toc(start);
%% polyfit solution
start=tic;
for iLine=1:numel(X)   
   coefs = polyfit(X{iLine}, Y{iLine}, 1);
   yf=polyval(coefs,X{iLine});
   K(iLine)=coefs(1);
   B(iLine)=coefs(2);

   R(iLine)=corr(Y{iLine},yf);
end
dur2(end+1)=toc(start);
end
```

[image]